# How to construct a 95% confidence interval for an average?

Tags: confidence-interval, poisson-distribution

I have some poisson distributed data, where I need to construct a 95% confidence interval for an average.

The sample is 50,

The average is: 15891

The standard deviation is 6733

How do I construct the confidence based on this?

Comment: If your data is Poisson distributed then mean = variance and it does not seems to be like this in your case...

Comment: The data is given, not something I've calculated. It should be correct for me to make a confidence interval on the average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), your average is - under certain assumptions - normally distributed. These assumptions will "usually" hold, let's assume they do here. $n=50$ is usually enough for an asymptotic treatment.

You can calculate the [standard error of the mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Standard_error_of_the_mean) like this:

$$ SE = \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{6733}{\sqrt{50}} \approx 952 $$

Your confidence interval is therefore

$$ 15891\pm 1.96\times 952 \approx [14025,17757].$$

(The factor of $\pm 1.96$ comes from the 2.5% and 97.5% quantile of the standard normal distribution.)

However, this is the general case. As [Tim notes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184811/how-to-construct-a-95-confidence-interval-for-an-average#comment351012_184811), data with an average of 15891 and a standard deviation of 6733 does not appear to be Poisson distributed, where you would expect the mean and variance to be equal (up to sampling variation). If you *actually* have Poisson data, [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/15371/1352) may be helpful. Essentially, for "sufficiently large" samples ($n=50$ should qualify), you would take the route outlined here, relying on asymptotic normality. For smaller samples, there are specialized techniques linked to there.