# Confidence intervals for the mean of a sample of counts

Tags: confidence-interval, poisson-distribution, count-data

I'm sure the answer to this question is obvious, but I can't seem to find it!

How do you calculate the confidence interval around the mean of a sample of counts?

I've made an example below in R, where I've bootstrapped confidence intervals. How do you calculate this using a formula? Is there a function in R?

```
# example sample of counts (n = 50, 'true' mean = 5)
set.seed(25); d <- rpois(50, 5)

# mean
mean(d)

# bootstrapped confidence intervals
B <- sample(d, 50 * 1000, replace = T)
B <- matrix(B, ncol = 1000)
B <- colMeans(B)
quantile(B, c(0.025, 0.975))

# mean = 4.72 (95% CI 4.14-5.34)
```

Comment: Several Poisson CI's are in common use. Two of them [illustrated here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401754/determining-confidence-interval-with-one-observation-for-poisson-distribution/401786#401786). Using @Demetri's (+1) simulated sample, R code `set.seed(25); d =  rpois(50, 5); pm = c(-1,1); (t + 2 * pm* 1.96*sqrt(t+1))/50` returns (3.513047, 5.926953).

Comment: Your code example uses Poisson counts. Is it your intention that the question be specifically about inference for the Poisson, or it is about counts more generally (as the title might suggest)?

Comment: @Glen_b I was thinking about poisson counts, but I can think of times when more general counts would be useful. Presumably the bootstrap method would work fine regardless of the distribution, and I guess if you assume another distribution you could use a regression model (e.g. negative binomial) as in Demitri's answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bit nuanced.

You could pull out the big guns and use a poisson regression

```
# example sample of counts (n = 50, 'true' mean = 5)
set.seed(25)
d <- rpois(50, 5)

model = glm(d~1, family = poisson)

exp(confint(model))
>>>    2.5 %   97.5 % 
     4.143126 5.348048
```

Or you could use the normal approximation since, as $\lambda$ gets big enough, the poisson starts to look a lot like a normal (though this only really happens when $\lambda$ is really really big).  Be warned, if your sample is small and your $\lambda$ is close to zero, this may result in the CI covering values less than 0

```
mu = mean(d)
se = sd(d)/sqrt(length(d))

c(mu-1.96*se, mu+1.96*se)

>>>[1] 4.124606 5.315394
```

That the two estimates differ is perfectly acceptable since they make different assumptions.  I would always prefer the former since the CI is computed using profile likelihood estimates.

Lastly, there is the procedure defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Confidence_interval) though I think it adds little value over using `glm`.

Here are some simulations to explore the coverage properties for both methods given your data generating process:

```
set.seed(0)
simGlmCi<-function(){
  d <- rpois(50, 5)
  model = glm(d~1)
  ci = confint(model)
  covered = (5<ci[2])&(ci[1]<5)
  return(covered)
}

sims = purrr::rerun(1000,simGlmCi()) 
coverage = mean(unlist(sims))
coverage
>>>0.951


simNormalCi<-function(){
  d <- rpois(50, 5)
  mu = mean(d)
  se = sd(d)/sqrt(length(d))
  covered = (5<mu+1.96*se)&(mu-1.96*se)
  return(covered)
}

sims = purrr::rerun(1000,simNormalCi()) 
coverage = mean(unlist(sims))
coverage
>>>0.964
```

You might be better off with the profile likelihood approach since it seems the normal approach is a bit permissive.